# Format csv data and write each row to a json

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write each row of a csv to a json (this will then be posted and looped back through so overwriting the json file is not a big deal here).  I have code which seems to do this well enough, but also need to some of the data to be floats/integers rather than strings.

I have a method which works for this in other places, but cannot manage to get the two to agree with each other.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to be able to format the csv data before sending it out as a json?  Below is the code for when headers are left in, though I also have a tweaked version which just has raw data in the csv and uses fieldnames for the headers instead.

```
import csv
import json

input_file = 'Test3.csv'
output_file_template = 'Test.json'

with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    rows = list(reader)

for i in range(len(rows)):
    out = json.dumps(rows[1*i:1*(i+1)])
    with open(output_file_template.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write(out)
```

Data is in a format like this:

OrderType   OrderStatus OrderDateTime   SettlementDate  MarketId    OrderRoute

Sale    Executed    18/11/2016  23/11/2016  1   None

Sale    Executed    18/11/2016  23/11/2016  1   None

Sale    Executed    18/11/2016  23/11/2016  1   None

With row[4] producing the key error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop if the float/int data is consistently in the same spot, you can simply cast the values.

```
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    row[0] = int(row[0]) # this column stores ints
    row[1] = float(row[1]) # this column stores floats
    out = json.dumps([row])
    with open(output_file_template.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write(out)
```

I don't know if columns 0 and 1 hold ints and floats, but you can change that as necessary.

#### Update:

It appears `row` is an `OrderedDict`, so you'll just need to use the key instead of an index:

```
row['MarketId'] = int(row['MarketId'])
```

Comment: The float and int data does always occur in the same place - I've just tried what you've suggested and it keeps throwing up key errors however.  Any idea where to go from there?

Comment: Edited with data examples.  The column which is causing an issue is row[4] - though this generally seems to happen for any column I try to work with.

Comment: The print looks like this: OrderedDict([('OrderType', 'Sale'), ('OrderStatus', 'Executed'), ('OrderDateTime', '18/11/2016'), ('SettlementDate', '23/11/2016'), ('MarketId', '1')])